# In this program to print prime numbers between two numbers, compiler is giving warning that "Parameter a and n are never used" — what does it mean?

Tags: c

WAP to print prime numbers between two numbers by functions.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int primenumbers(int a,int n);
void main()
{
    int a,n,result,i,f;
    clrscr();
    printf("enter the starting element and ending element");
    scanf("%d%d",&a,&n);
}
```

I want to print prime numbers between a and n.

```
for(i=a;i<=n;i++)
{
    f=primenumbers(a,n);
    if(f==0&&n!=1)
        printf("%d is prime",i);
    }
    getch();
}

int primenumbers(int a, int n)
{
    int i,j,f;
    for(j=2;j<=(i/2);j++)
    {
        if(i%j==0)
        {
            f=1;
            break;
        }
    }
    return f;
}
```

> - error **parameter a is never used**
> - error **parameter n is never used**

Comment: This error message seems pretty clear, as error messages go. Neither parameter `a` nor parameter `n` are used in the `primeNumbers` function.

Comment: Your `primenumbers()` function takes two arguments which are called `a` and `n` in the function.  But the code in the function never uses either `a` or `n` — hence the warning.  Your function isn't paying any attention to what it is being told to do.  Note that you should probably end your `printf()` format string with a newline.

Comment: Moreover the you are using `i` in function `primenumbers` which is an *uninitialised variable* and the compiler might also have warned you about it. The `i` in that function is a *different* `i` from the one in `main`. Since `main` is looping between `a` and `n` I suggest the function should be `int primenumbers(int i)` and you remove its other `int i` declaration. You would then call it with `f=primenumbers(i);`

Answer (score 0):

You get the warning simply because the function parameters `a` and `n` isn't used in the function.

There see to be some basic misunderstanding in your code. You have a loop in `main` going from `a` to `n` using `i` as the counter variable. However, when you call `primenumbers` you call it using `a` and `n` instead of `i`.

I guess the function should receive **one** number and return whether that number is a prime. So the call in `main` should be:

```
for(i=a;i<=n;i++)
{
    f=primenumbers(i);  // Notice i instead of a and n
    if (f==0 && n!=1)
        printf("%d is prime",i);
}
```

Then you need to change your function as well.

```
int primenumbers(int number)
{
    int j;
    int f = 0;     // Remember to initialize f

    for(j=2; j<=(number/2); j++)   // Notice the use of number
    {
        if (number % j == 0)       // Notice the use of number
        {
           // Not a prime
            f=1;
            break;
        }
    }

    return f;
}
```

There is some improvements that should be made to the code above.

You  have this code in `main`

```
    if (f==0 && n!=1)  // It is a bad idea to let main check for 1
                       // the function should handle all numbers
                       //
                       // Further it is unusual to return the value
                       // 0 for TRUE. Normally we use 1 for true
```

So change main like:

```
for(i=a;i<=n;i++)
{
    if (primenumber(i))
        printf("%d is prime",i);
}
```

and the function

```
// This function returns 1 if number is a prime, otherwise it returns 0
int primenumber(int number)
{
    int j;

    if (number < 2) return 0;  // Not a prime

    for(j=2; j<=(number/2); j++)
    {
        if (number % j == 0)     
        {
           // Not a prime
           return 0;
        }
    }

    // It is a prime
    return 1;
}
```